# Can transaction be a class?

Tags: java, c#, oop, object-oriented-analysis

Yesterday I was asked in the interview, "Can transaction be a class?"

I said, "yes". He replied class or a function?

I replied if it has a very simple functionality it can be a function but it should be a class.

He said ok let's accept it for the moment that it can be a class. Write its code.

I wrote:

```
class transaction{
 int timestamp;
 Account acc;
 int type;

 public transaction(int timestamp,int type,Account acc){
     this.timestamp = timestamp; this.int = int ; this.acc =acc;
 }

 public withdraw ( double amount){
     acc.amount -= amount;
 }

 //And other type of transaction function, like add money etc.

}
```

Let me know if I answered it right or wrong, I couldn't perceive much from his expressions.

Answer (score 4):

`Transaction` is a *noun*, and therefore it should be modeled as an object. Messages (or for that matter, functions) are *verbs* and are therefore well suited to perform actions. A `transaction` (*noun*) may `start` (*verb*), `end` (*verb*) or `abort` (*verb*) and should be completely `revert`ed (*verb*) or `commit`ted (*verb*).

**EDIT**

@AlexeiLevenkov's remark in the comments section correctly points out that `withdraw` is not a proper `Transaction` message. A proper message for the `withdraw` operation would be (Smalltalk syntax)

```
anAccount withdraw: anAmount in: aTransaction
```

making `withdraw:in:` the appropriate `Account` operation (method). Given the general nature of `Transaction` it should implement a more agnostic method in the lines of

```
aTransaction do: aBlock
    aTransaction start
    [aBlock value] ifCurtailed: [aTransaction abort].
    aTransaction commit
```

In this way we would have

```
anAccount withdraw: anAmount in: aTransaction
    aTransaction do: [anAccount withdraw: anAmount]
```

What's interesting in the `Transaction` object is its ability to capture (and model) the basic protocol `start`, `commit`, `abort` along with the method `do:` for general evaluation of generic operations (represented by Smalltalk blocks in my coding.)

Comment: Yes, you were right. Hopefully, the guy who asked has a good OOP education too.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I'd say that "withdrawal" is not operation of  transaction object as shown in original sample, but type of transaction... I really doubt OP was anywhere close to what interviewer was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I probably would have written it more like this:

```
public interface IRecord
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp {get;set;}
}

public enum TransactionType 
{
    Debit , Credit
}

public class Transaction : IRecord
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
    public TransactionType Type {get;set;}
    public Account TargetAccount {get;set;} 
}

public class Atm 
{
    private List<Tuple<Acount,Transaction>> _record = new List<Tuple<Account,Transaction>>();
    private ICashHandler _cashHandler;

    public Atm(ICashHandler handler)
    {
        _cashHandler = handler;
    }

    public void Withdraw(Account account, decimal amount)
    {
        _record.Add(Tuple.Create(account, 
            new Transaction {
                TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
                Amount = amount,
                Type = TransactionType.Debit,
                TargetAccount = account
            })
        );

        _cashHandler.Dispense(amount);
    }

    public void Deposit(Account account)
    {
        decimal amount;

        if( _cashHandler.TakeDeposit( out amount ) ) 
        {

            _record.Add(Tuple.Create(account, 
                new Transaction {
                    TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
                    Amount = amount,
                    Type = TransactionType.Credit,
                    TargetAccount = account
                })
            );
        }

    }

}
```

Just a simple example, should have checks for account amounts etc.

Idea is that the transaction is a record, the action of the transaction occurring would be the method (which in this case is handled by the Atm class). The transaction class should not have actions like withdrawal and deposit, it is simple a record of an action on an account, not the actual action.